# Components not displaying on JFrame time-to-time

Tags: java, jframe

I have a JFrame Gridlayout with components like buttons, JTextfields, JLabels.

Sometimes when I execute the file, I see an empty frame. So I have to maximize the screen, the components come back. and then when I go back to normal window, the components are still visible.

Sometimes when I execute the file, I see the components right away. As they should be.

Can anyone explain this phenomena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the items aren't getting painted or repainted at the correct time.  Make sure you are not making the frame visible first and then adding components, or if you are making sure you revalidate() or repaint() after making changes to something that you have already made visible.

Comment: thanks. that was exactly the problem. I was setting it visible before adding the components. After setting it visible after adding the components, I don't have that 'phenomena' any more. thanks again

Comment: Also verify you are creating ALL of the Swing components on the event dispatch thread, and updating their state on the EDT as well.  Even creating components must be done on the EDT.